# What is com.sun.bigbrother.javanet or BigBrother Datamining Project?

Tags: maven

Does anyone know what the maven repository `com.sun.bigbrother.javanet` or ["BigBrother Datamining Project"](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.bigbrother.javanet/bigbrother-javanet/1)
is doing? It appears in my maven tree and I have no idea where it comes from. Google gives me no hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See also [`bigbrother` on Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|bigbrother). The POM of `ci-bayes` says: *"Module for classifying data based on various Bayesian algorithms".* See also [Using CI-Bayes](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1363646/Using-CI-Bayes).